# What is the opposite of the perfect aspect?

Tags: grammar, terminology

Most tenses exist in a perfect and non-perfect form, e.g. present vs. present perfect and past continuous vs. past perfect continuous. What is the group of tenses that are not perfect called?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperfect

Comment: @mplungjan: No, imperfect is always past. The word I seek would also describe "I will eat" (but not "I will have eaten"). (If I read the article correctly.)

Comment: The tenses are three: Pesent, Past, Future. The other parts we call aspects: Continuous, Simple, Perfect. Just as there is no opposite to either 'Simple' or 'Continuous', there is no opposite to 'Perfect'.

Comment: @Karl: Surely, continuous and perfect are not mutually exclusive. "I have been eating" is present perfect continuous.

Comment: @Tim: Which is precisely why they cannot be opposites of each other. The fact that they refer to different things does not make them opposites, just as red and green are not 'opposites'. If something is not the perfect aspect, it is simply something else.

Comment: @Karl: I know that Continuous is not the opposite of Perfect. I am asking for the opposite of Perfect, for a better word than "Non-perfect". (Thanks for pointing out that it's called an aspect, though.)

Comment: And I am telling you @Tim, that there isn't one. Just because something isn't one thing, doesn't mean it has to be it's opposite. If a piece of furniture isn't a chair but a table, that doesn't mean it is the opposite of chair; it merely means that it is something else.

Comment: @Karl: Ok. If the answer is that there isn't one, please write an Answer -- that's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Karl: I disagree on your parallell to furniture. A verb can be any combination of continuous/non-continuous and perfect/non-perfect, but a piece of furniture can not be any combination of chair/non-chair and table/non-table (unless it's a silly piece of furniture).

Comment: Fair enough. It just didn't seem substantial enough for an Answer. I will do so now.

Comment: But you do see that being different is not the same as being opposite? That's the point I was making with the furniture analogy.

Comment: @Karl: I really don't understand. I think of tenses and aspects as being any combination of {past, present, future} x {perfect, non-perfect} x {continuous, non-continuous}. Perfect/non-perfect is a dichotomy that does not affect the possible tenses or continuousnesses. I don't see why there couldn't be a better word for non-perfect and non-continuous. The chair/non-chair would be an appropriate answer if I asked for the opposite of past or present.

Comment: I'll start a new question on this, since I find the different categorizations interesting.

Comment: But if it is non-continuous, then you simply don't refer to its continuousness; you refer to what it is, rather than what it isn't. You wouldn't say that something is non-green, you would simply say that it is red (or whatever).

Comment: He ate an apple. -- You wouldn't say that this is past non-continuous non-perfect. You would just call it past simple. You see?

Comment: They are in fact often called the "non-perfect" tenses. Karl is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They’re called non-perfect.

Likewise, the uses of verbs that aren’t finite are non-finite. Honestly, there’s enough terminology in grammar already without inventing an opposite for every term!

Comment: But... imperfect means non-perfect no :) ? The fact that imperfect is usually only used to refer to a past test is complicating matters. The *imperfective aspect*, though, usually means what it states. However, it's not completely clear if OP is asking about aspects or tenses.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it is important to point out that the **tenses** are only three: Past, Present and Future. Tense refers directly to *time*.

'Simple', 'Continuous' (progressive) and 'Perfect' are **aspects**, along with the fourth 'perfect continuous' which satisfies the criteria for both 'perfect' and 'continuous'. These refer to *state of an action*.

As for opposites, different aspects refer to different states. If an action is not continuous, then it is something else. Being different does not make it 'opposite'.

So, put simply: There is no 'opposite' for the perfect aspect, though there are other aspects.

Hope that helps

Comment: ((Above, I gave the analogy of different types of furniture but I fear that is too vast. Consider the states of water. Though they are all the same substance, they could either be solid, liquid or gas. Neither of these states is the opposite of the others, just a different state.))

Comment: Also, incase anybody feels the need to be very accurate about this, 'Future' is *technically* not a tense as it doesn't inflect the verb. I don't think it is necessary to point that out in my answer though.

Comment: I am still critical toward this categorization of aspects. If "simple" is an aspect, than so is "continuous perfect". They're either those four or two (cont. and perf.).

Comment: Oh, I see your point now. Yes, 'perfect continuous' is technically a fourth aspect, but is made up of the other two. That there are four rather than three still doesn't create any question about opposites, I'm afraid. I'll include an edit to make that clearer.

Comment: Aspects are not "states of the action" or any other property of the action: they are properties of how you are regarding or referring to the action: "I watched it" and "I was watching it" can refer to the same action, but regarding it in different ways.

Comment: @ColinFine, of course they refer to the same action but they refer to a different state of the action. What I mean to say is that when you use continuous, the action is in occurrence. When you use perfect, the action is complete. I think 'state' is as good a word to explain this as any. Using your words, I would still say that we are regarding it in different states of its instance.

Comment: This remains in lieu of a better term.

Comment: @Karl, no, they don't refer to a different state of the action, they express a difference in the way the speaker is referring to the action. "He went to the shops" and "He has gone to the shops" can both be used to refer to the same event (as a whole), but picking out different characteristics (I nearly said "aspects") of it.

Comment: If there is a “perfect continuous” aspect, there must also be a “past future” tense, because just like perfect and continuous, past and future are totally orthogonal: *I see / saw / will see / would see.*

Answer (score 0):

Perfect and continuous are not mutually exclusive, and therefore can be used individually or together, giving three aspects.  Those usages that include neither are called simple.  Thus simple, while not the "opposite" of perfect, excludes both perfect and continuous.

Expressed tabularly, there are four cases -- s, p, c, pc -- which can be used in all tenses, where s indicates the absence of either p or c.

Comment: I was looking for a collective word for the s and c cases, i.e. those which are not perfect.